# working in same source code among a group of programmers in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have been using visual studio 2010 for developing a windows based software by using vb.net and MSSQL 2005 ,

this is my first experience to work with a group , before this I have done my project individually,

My question is this , How all of the members in a group can work on the same source code ? 
does visual studio 2010 have any features to handle some users which want to work in the same source code ! ?

Thanks u very much in advance

Comment: have you ever heard the word server version control `SVN` or `TFS`

Comment: Team Foundation Server is the answer....http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fda2bad5(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can normally use a source control system like CVS or SVN to do this. You can also use Team Foundation Server (TFS) which is an Application Life cycle Management Tool (ALM) that comes along with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thnaks, I have installed visualsvn ,, i hope it can solve my problem